# Problems with Applicative-style Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have the following ADT:

```
type Program = [Expr]
data Expr =
    Num Int
    | Bool Bool
    | Binding String Expr
    deriving (Show)
```

Here's a parser for variable-binding expressions, of the form `lhs is rhs`.

```
binding :: Parser Expr
binding = do
    lhs <- word
    spaces
    string "is"
    spaces
    rhs <- expr
    return $ Binding lhs rhs
```

It works fine, but when I try to convert it into applicative style, it gives the wrong result.

```
binding :: Parser Expr
binding = Binding <$> word <* (spaces *> string "is" *> spaces) *> expr
```

Replacing `*>` with `>>` in the parenthesised portion didn't work either. What's the difference between these two implementations? Is there a combinator for composing two parsers and ignoring the result of both?

Trying to debug with `Debug.trace` didn't work either... Nothing was printed.

```
binding :: Parser Expr
binding = (\x y -> trace (show (x, y)) (Binding x y)) <$> word <* (spaces *> string "is" *> spaces) *> expr
```

The rest of the parser, for context:

```
word :: Parser String
word = many1 letter

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = binding <|> atom

program :: Parser Program
program = do
    spaces
    result <- many (expr <* spaces)
    return result
```

Comment: Quick guess, but shouldn't you be using `(<*>)` after `word` in  your `binding` definition? I.e: `binding = Binding <$> word <*> (spaces *> string "is" *> spaces) *> expr`

Comment: Does this work? Perhaps you should provide more of your code. http://lpaste.net/121008

Comment: You spotted that quickly. :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that `<$>` and `<*>` etc. are left associative. This means that your line:

```
binding = Binding <$> word <* (spaces *> string "is" *> spaces) *> expr
```

will be interpreted as

```
binding = (Binding <$> word <* (spaces *> string "is" *> spaces)) *> expr
```

This means that it will parse and then ignore everything before the last expr. As @icktoofay said, you can write the intended version as:

```
binding = Binding <$> word <* spaces <* string "is" <* spaces <*> expr
```

and not need any parenthesis at all, because of the left associativity.

Answer (score 6):

@danem is right, try:

```
binding :: Parser Expr
binding = Binding <$> word <*> (spaces *> string "is" *> spaces *> expr)
```

Full source: http://lpaste.net/121011

Your original definition is parsed this way:

```
binding = ((Binding <$> word) <* (spaces *> string "is" *> spaces)) *> expr
```

i.e. it has the form `something *> expr`, and so the returned value is determined solely by the last `expr`. The lhs and `is` token are parsed but then discarded.

Here is how the sub-expressions type check:

```
Binding                     :: String -> Expr -> Expr
(Binding <$> word)          :: Parser (Expr -> Expr)
(Binding <$> word) <* (...) :: Parser (Expr -> Expr)
```

So we see that everything type checks due to currying and the fact that we are discarding the result of `something`.

Comment: That looks right (although you could remove the parentheses with `Binding <$> word <* spaces <* string "is" <* spaces <*> expr`), but I think adding a little explanation of what was wrong with the attempted solution and why this one works would make this a more valuable answer.

Comment: Interesting alternative solution! It's given me new understanding of how these operators work.